# Splitting a b'' returns error in Python3.7

Tags: python, subprocess

Currently I am writing a script in Python3. From that I will need to call a script which is written in Python2.

I am doing this using `subprocess` doing the following:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> my_command = 'python,script_in_py2.py,arg1,arg2'
>>> process = subprocess.Popen(my_command.split(','), stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
>>> output, error = process.communicate()
```

Just for clarification, `arg1` and `arg2` can have spaces that is why I am splitting the command by commas instead.

After that part has been run, `output` receives, clearly the output of the Python2 script.
It looks something like:

`b'output\nOf\nScript\nIn\nPython2\nIs\nHere\n'`

This looks like a bytes object to me. However when calling `>>> output.split('\n')`, I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Also when trying `>>> type(output)` it returns `<class 'bytes'>`, which is only confusing me more.

Any ideas as to why is this happening?

Comment: Yes, it's a bytes object - the problem is that *`'/n'` isn't*. `.split(b'\n')` will work fine.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it weirdly makes very much sense to me now. Thank you for pointing that out. For the moment I was solving it by first decoding `output` and then splitting.

Comment: Why is `my_command = 'python,script_in_py2.py,arg1,arg2'` instead of `my_command = ['python', 'script_in_py2.py', 'arg1', 'arg2']`?

Comment: you can also decode bytes to string before split - `output.decode().split('\n')`

Comment: @MadPhysicst ```my_command``` looks like that because after using ```.split(',')``` on it, it will return a list just like the one you wrote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not that the object you're trying to split is the wrong type, the problem is the delimiter you're trying to split by is not the same type as the thing you're trying to split.

```py
>>>b'a\nb'.split('\n')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

>>>b'a\nb'.split(b'\n')
[b'a', b'b']
```

So as you can see, if you want to split a bytes-like object, you need to pass a bytes-like object as an argument. Just change `.split('\n')` to `.split(b'\n')`